# Why does the sort function of list container not working

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am trying the sort function of list container, passing a function object and function pointer as the compare function.
But somehow, the function object version did not work out. 
the output for `l.sort(MylessFuncObj())` is:

```
1
2
3
5
45
```

though I expected the output to be 1 2 3 45 5. another thing I do not quite understand is that `l.sort(MylessFuncObj())` did work well if used it before `l.sort()`.

I just started learning cpp, I am really stuck..

```
    #include <list>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class MylessFuncObj
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b){
            return (a%10)<(b%10);
        }

    };
    bool Mylessfunc(const int &a, const int &b){
        return (a%10)<(b%10);
    }

int main()
{
    list<int> l={1, 2, 3, 45,5};
    l.sort(Mylessfunc);
    for(int j:l) cout<<j<<endl;
    l.sort();
    cout<<endl;
    for(int j:l) cout<<j<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    l.sort(MylessFuncObj());
    for(int j:l)
    cout<<j<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integers aren't sorted lexicographically...... they're sorted by value....... do you really sort quantities of things this way in real life?

Comment: Did you try with different instances of the list initialized with the same set of values instead of sorting the same list multiple times?

Comment: It's correctly sorted according to your sort function. Why do you think that 45 must come before 5?

Comment: Well, 45 mod 10 is 5 and 5 mod 10 is 5. So *why* did you expect 45 to be less than 5 according to your comparison functor?

Comment: Thanks guys, I made a mistake, thanks again for your prompt responses to my first stackoverflow question!

Answer (score 1):

45 and 5 compare as equal according to your comparison function, so they can appear in any order. List sort is stable, so they will remain in the order they were in originally.

Initially , this order was `45 5`, and this is what your first print should display. After `l.sort()` (using the default comparison function), the order becomes `5 45` and any further sorts with your custom comparison function will retain this order.